# Excel CSV format how to save ending 0?

Tags: excel, csv

I need a file in csv format to upload to another system. However , it is dropping the ending 0 in numbers where there is a decimal point e.g 72.20

I need this ending 0. I tried saving as a number and it converts but when I save and re-enter the file the number has dropped the 0 again. Tried saving as currency without symbol etc. Nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `="72.20"` would preserve things as text, `TEXT(.., "0.00")` can be used to do this dynamically. This is still no hard guarantee the value would be preserved on the other end, mind you, that would depend on the data type used for storage.